# How to fetch the second column of a file using `for` loop in linux?

Tags: linux

How to fetch the second column of a file using `for` loop in linux?
`ATTACHMENT vol-f66 i-26048111  /dev/sda1   attached    2013-11-20T06:42:49+0000    true`
`ATTACHMENT vol-3db i-e1c443d6  /dev/sda1   attached    2013-11-21T12:38:09+0000    true`

i want to implement something like this-

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do call ec2-create-snapshot %%s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed it to `awk '{print $2}'`. You may edit the delimiter which is `\n` right now, and do away with the `for` loop too.

Example-

```
echo "ATTACHMENT vol-f66 i-26048111 /dev/sda1 attached 2013-11-20T06:42:49+0000 true 
ATTACHMENT vol-3db i-e1c443d6 /dev/sda1 attached 2013-11-21T12:38:09+0000 true
ATTACHMENT vol-sdb i-e1c443d6 /dev/sda1 attached 2013-11-21T12:38:09+0000 true
ATTACHMENT vol-3ss i-e1c443d6 /dev/sda1 attached 2013-11-21T12:38:09+0000 true" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Returns-

```
vol-f66
vol-3db
vol-sdb
vol-3ss
```

Comment: how to fetch the second column only ? can you write the code for it ?

Comment: i want to do this `
for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do call ec2-create-snapshot %%s`

Comment: Edit and put this in your question. Cannot make any sense of it here.